# Sending a POST request to API with localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, unirest

I am sending an image to an API using my localhost address but for some reason it doesn't identify the image. It works fine if I use links on google. The code looks something like this:

```
unirest.post(requestString)
   .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
   .field("urls", "http://localhost:4000/uploads/1570544614486-test.jpg")
   .field("album", ALBUM_NAME)
   .field("albumkey", ALBUM_KEY)
   .field("entryid", entryId)
   .end(result => {
       console.log(result.body);
});
```

I believe this will work once on a domain but I need it to work now for testing. How can I make this work using my localhost?

Comment: Do you habe any error in the browser Javascript console ? ( F12 ) you might have a cross-origin problem.

Comment: How exactly do you expect a remote API to resolve a `localhost` URL?

Comment: error: 'Empty result, possibly no faces detected in the image!'- that's the error I get

Comment: @esqew So, it is not possible?

Comment: If you image is hosted on your localhost server, and you are sending an url like ( http://localhost:3000/img/your_image.png) it won't work. localhost refer to your own computer, the API don't have access to that.

Comment: @Roger It is possible, you'll have to change the structure of your request. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't exactly specified what API you're reaching out to, so your mileage may vary with different APIs.

However, based on your error message, I've determined you're trying to leverage the [Lambda Face Recognition and Face Detection API via RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection?endpoint=53aa3244e4b059614033ed20). This (linked) docs for this web service *clearly* show that the `urls` parameter you're attempting to use with your `localhost` URL above is actually meant to hold a comma-separated set of URLs to publicly-accessible image files. The remote API can't possibly resolve `localhost` in this context, because (a) it can't possibly have any idea what IP `localhost` should refer to, and (b) it's highly likely that your `localhost` here doesn't respond to HTTP requests from the broader Internet.

Instead, modify your request to use the `files` parameter (type `binary`) to upload the raw binary data for your image(s).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is what I did instead. I simply used regex to get the filename and used fs to link to the path.